# iOS : Post array of strings to web service for the following JSON

Tags: ios, json

1. How to get the following response from a "post" webservice.
2. I have an array of strings called textArray.
   How to post that textArray for the key @"Answer" in the following response.

   ```
         {
           "ProjID": "78",
           "Uid": "12",
           "EmailID": "ratnam_nv@yahoo.com",
           "ProjectInviterFQAnswers": [{
               "slno": "1",
               "Answer": "a1",
               "order": "1",
               "flag": "F"
           }, {
               "slno": "2",
               "Answer": "a1",
               "order": "2",
               "flag": "F"
           }, {
               "slno": "1",
               "Answer": "a1",
               "order": "2",
               "flag": "Q"
           }
           ]
       };
   ```

Here's what I tried so far

```
NSError *error = Nil;
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];


NSDictionary *dictionaryArray1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"slno", @"a1", @"Answer", @"1", @"order", @"F", @"Flag", nil];

NSDictionary *dictionaryArray2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2", @"slno", @"a1", @"Answer", @"1", @"order", @"F", @"Flag", nil];

NSDictionary *dictionaryArray3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"slno", @"a1", @"Answer", @"2", @"order", @"Q", @"Flag", nil];

NSArray *arrayAnswer = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dictionaryArray1, dictionaryArray2, dictionaryArray3, nil];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"78", @"ProjID", @"12", @"UID", @"ratnam_nv@yahoo.com", @"EmailID", arrayAnswer, @"ProjectInviterFQAnswer", nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@" someurl "];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        if(error || !data)
        {
            NSLog(@"JSON Data not posted!");
            [activity stopAnimating];
            UIAlertView *alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Data not saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertMessage show];
        }
        else
        {
            [activity startAnimating];
            NSLog(@"JSON data posted! :)");
            NSError *error = Nil;
            NSJSONSerialization *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Response is %@", jsonObject); //Not getting the response here Message = "An error has occurred."
            [activity stopAnimating];
        }

    }];
```

Comment: What you have tried? What problem you are facing? If you have tried nothing by your self than first try and than come with more specific issue.

Comment: Make key/value pair using NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary.
Good Luck !!

Comment: Where is the code where you have played with JSON? what do u mean by posted? Do u want to send JSON on server (because it is general meaning of posting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be careful:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"slno", @"Answer", @"order", @"flage", nil];
```

but you have:

```
"flag": "Q"
```

flage != flag.

That's why it is good to use constants!

**Next, regarding you question:**

First you have to transform the JSON into a NSDictionary.

After:

```
NSArray * array = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"ProjectInviterFQAnswer"];
for(NSMutableDictionary * dict in array){
     [dict setValue:<put here anything you want> forKey:@""];
}
```

after you do that, create a new JSON from jsonDict, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to convert the response into dictionary and the set the value of answer your textArray String and then again convert it into json string