# Easier way to send JSON Data with Objective-C to PHP server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asihttprequest

I have a PHP RESTful server that I connect to to invoke methods based on the URL path called from my objective-c program. I use the `ASIHTTPRequest` and `SBJson`.

Everything works well but I'm doing requests in different controllers and now duplicated methods are in all those controllers. What is the best way to abstract that code (requests) in a single class, so I can easily re-use the code, so I can keep the controllers more simple.

Please save me from what I feel to be a redundant and repetitive coding sequence.

I have tried to make a singleton class, but each view controller requires different request connect points, and most view controllers require specific actions to be called when the succeeded method is called and Im not sure how to handle it all.

Here is what my code template currently looks like in the Objective-c program:

```
//*1) Somewhere at the top of my .m file I have this*

//These are the suffixes to the URL path that I connect to at my server, 
//depending on the action required 
NSString *const RequestCreateCustomer = @"Create/Customer";
NSString *const RequestUpdateCustomer = @"Update/Customer";
NSString *const RequestDeleteCustomer = @"Delete/Customer";

//*2) Then I have my connection invocation code*

//Method invocation, all of them look something like this
-navigationButton{
...
    [self retrieveWithRequestStringType:RequestUpdateCustomer];
}

-(void)retrieveWithRequestStringType:(NSString*)typeOfRequest{

    NSLog(@"Retrieve %@ method called", typeOfRequest);
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Secure/CB/%@", @"http://www.defaultStapleURLToMyServer.com/CB", typeOfRequest];
    NSString *encodedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:encodedUrlString];

    serverRequest = nil;
    serverRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [serverRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [serverRequest addRequestHeader:@"Request-Method" value:@"POST"];

    //Normally at this point depending on the request type, I prepare some data that needs to be sent along with the request

    NSMutableDictionary *completeDataArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    
    if([typeOfRequest isEqualToString:RequestCreateCustomer]){
        [serverRequest setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:RequestCreateCustomer forKey:@"RequestType"]];
        if( ! [self validateAndPrepareAllData:&completeDataArray]){
            return;
        }

    }
    else if([typeOfRequest isEqualToString:RequestUpdateCustomer]){
        [serverRequest setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:RequestUpdateCustomer forKey:@"RequestType"]];
        if( ! [self validateAndPrepareAllData:&completeDataArray]){
            return;
        }
    }
    else if([typeOfRequest isEqualToString:RequestDeleteCustomer]){
        [serverRequest setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:RequestDeleteCustomer forKey:@"RequestType"]];
        if( ! [self validateAndPrepareCustomerIdData:&completeDataArray]){
            return;
        }

    }

    NSString *jsonString = [completeDataArray JSONRepresentation];
    [serverRequest appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [serverRequest setDelegate:self];
    [serverRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestSucceeded:)];
    [serverRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [serverRequest startAsynchronous];
}


//*3) And heres the connection did succeed, and connection did fail methods*

-(void)requestSucceeded:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request{

    NSInteger statusCode = [[[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"StatusCode"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"StatusCode: %@", [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"StatusCode"]);

    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [myString JSONValue];

    switch (statusCode) {
        case 400:
        case 401:
        {
            NSLog(@"display error message");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[[request.responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Message"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            break;
        }
        case 200:
            NSLog(@"status code = 200 so successful");

            //Created customer request succeeded
            if([[[request userInfo] objectForKey:@"RequestType"] isEqualToString:RequestCreateCustomer]){
                [self.delegate addedCustomerVCWithCustomer:[[CustomerDataModel alloc] initWithJSONData:[JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"CustomerObject"]]];
                [self cancelModalView];

            } 
            //Edit customer request succeeded
            else if([[[request userInfo] objectForKey:@"RequestType"] isEqualToString:RequestUpdateCustomer]){
                [self.delegate editedCustomerVCWithCustomer:[[CustomerDataModel alloc] initWithJSONData:[JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"CustomerObject"]]];
                [self cancelModalView];
            }
            //Delete customer request succeeded
            else if([[[request userInfo] objectForKey:@"RequestType"] isEqualToString:RequestDeleteCustomer]){
                [self.delegate deletedCustomer:customer];
                [self cancelModalView];
            }
            break;
        default:
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"went to none: %d or %@", (int)statusCode, [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"StatusCode"]]];
            NSLog(@"went to none: %d or %@", (int)statusCode, [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"StatusCode"]);
            break;
    }
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}



-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request{

    if([[[request userInfo] objectForKey:@"RquestType"] isEqualToString:RequestCreateCustomer]){
        NSLog(@"retrieving states failed so trying again");
        [self addCustomerRequest];
    }
    else if(){
       //... you get the point
    }
}
```

Can someone help out with an alternative solution?

Comment: I tried a simple way. Have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706004/ios-post-array-of-strings-to-web-service-for-the-following-json

Comment: Hey thanks mate, you're using blocks which is nice, but it will still mean duplication across multiple view controllers which I dont really want at that sort of scale.

Answer (score 0):

create a new class that has blocks/delegate (but prefers block) on it.. let's say Request.h and Request.m.. and make a public method with a block parameter.. example

this should be public methods

```
typedef void(^CompletionBlock)(id results);
typedef void(^ErrorBlock)(NSError *error);
```

`- (void)setCompetionBlock:(CompletionBlock)block;` and

```
- (void)setErrorBlock:(ErrorBlock)error;
```

and make a variable name.. this should be private variables

```
CompletionBlock completionBlock;
ErrorBlock errorBlock;
```

and declare this methods in your .m

```
- (void)setCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlock)aCompletionBlock {
    completionBlock = [aCompletionBlock copy];
}

- (void)setErrorBlock:(ErrorBlock)aError {
    errorBlock = [aError copy];
}

- (void)reportSuccess:(id)results {
    if (completionBlock) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock(results);
        });
    }
}

- (void)reportFailure:(NSError *)error {
    if (errorBlock) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            errorBlock(error);
        });
    }
}
```

and call `[self reportSuccess:jsonSuccess];` under your success methods, in your code it is `-(void)requestSucceeded:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request{` and `[self reportFailure:NSerror*]` under `-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request`

and to call this class

```
Request *req = [Request alloc]init];
[req retrieveWithRequestStringType:@"sample"];
[req setCompletion:^(id result){

}];
[req setErrorBlock:(NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: Thank you for posting, the code seems all over the place, can you organise this a bit? It's confusing to look at. I'm trying to understand what goes where. What I dont want is repitition, but I also want an easy way to handle success and failed requests across different view controllers, that will behave differently depending on the view controller, some will disable fields, others will display alerts etc.

Comment: I tried to make sense of your post, and atm it still looks like I'll have to copy and paste chunks of code of `blocks` across different view controllers and I'm trying to avoid that Juan.

Comment: If you look at the code buddy, you can see that its not a shared isntance, and instead you're creating blocks for every type of request connection point to the server. I'm trying to keep the code clean so that I can have a shared instance, a singleton that will centralise and manage all of my connections. Let me know if you have a solution thats out there, since I cant find a solution that works off the bat